# python and error I"ndentationError"

Tags: python

I have a sequence as follows:

```
>gnl|GNOMON|230560472.m Model predicted by Gnomon on Homo sapiens unplaced genomic scaffold, alternate assembly HuRef DEGEN_1103279082069, whole genome shotgun sequence (NW_001841731.1)
GCCGGCGTTTGACCGCGCTTGGGTGGCCTGGGACCCTGTGGGAGGCTTCCCCGGCGCCGAGAGCCCTGGC
TGACGGCTGATGGGGAGGAGCCGGCGGGCGGAGAAGGCCACGGGCTCCCCAGTACCCTCACCTGCGCGGG
ATCGCTGCGGGAAACCAGGGGGAGCTTCGGCAGGGCCTGCAGAGAGGACAAGCGAAGTTAAGAGCCTAGT
GTACTTGCCGCTGGGAGCTGGGCTAGGCCCCCAACCTTTGCCCTGAAGATGCTGGCAGAGCAGGATGTTG
TAACGGGAAATGTCAGAAATACTGCAAGCAAACTGAAAACAACCCATCCATGTAGGAAAGAATAACACGG
ACTACACACTATGAGGAAACCACAGGGGAGTTTCAGGCCAGTCAGCTTTTGATCTTCAACTTTATAACTT
TCACCTTAGGATATGACGAGCCCACCGGAGTTTCAAAAATGGTATCATTTTGTATCAGGCTTGTTTTTTA
CACTCTTGGTTTCTCACAGAGATAGGTGGTTTCTCCTTAAAATCGAACATTTATATGATGCATTTTACTG
TAGTTACTATCAGAAAAGTTAGTTTTCCCAAATTTAAGTTCACTCTGGGGTACTATAGCGTGAATGTAGT
TCATTCTGTTGAGCTAGTTGTTCATGTTAGTGTAGTTCACATATTTATCTGGAACTCAAAAATGAGGGGT
TGAGAGGGGAAGCTAAAATTCAAAACATGTCCAAATATATAATTTTAATATTTTACTTTATATTTAAAAT
AGAAAAGCAATTGATTCTAGAATTAGACTAATTGCTAGCATTGCTAGGATATATAAAATGAAGCTGAATG
TTTTAACTCTGGAATTTTTCTGAATAGTCTAAGAAATAAGGCTGAAGTGTATCACTTGCCTTAAGTTTAC
TTTTGCGTGTGTGTTTTAATTTTGTTCAGTGGGGCTTTCACTTAAAAAAAAAACCATAATATTATTACCT
GGATAAAAAATACAGCTGAAAGTAGATCACTTTATCTTTAAGCAGAAGGATGGAAATAGAAGAATTTTAA
GAATGTATTGGTTGAAAAACATCTATATTATTTTATTTTTATTTCTCTTCTTGTGGGAGTAAAATAATTT
CCAACCAAATCAGTCCACCTAGATTATACACTGTTCAGTTTGTTTTCTGCCCTGCAGCACAAGCAATAAC
CAGCAGAGACTGGAACCACAGCTGAGGCTCTGTAAATGAGTTGACTGCTAAGGACTTCATGGGGATATTA
ACCTGGGGCATTAAGAGAATCAACATGCTAAAGTACTTGGAGACAGCTCTGTAATGTTTTATGAGGTTTT
TTGTTTTTTTTTTTTGAGACAGAGTCTTGCACTGTCGCCCAGGCTGG
```

I try to translate it to protein. I used other posts to do so, but I get several error when i run it.

The code is as follows:

```
import re
from itertools import takewhile
from collections import Counter

    # prints how many start and stop codons are in the sequence 

   pat = re.compile(r"(TAA|TGA|TAG|ATG)") #additional space required!
   c = re.findall(pat,sequence) #additional space required!
   print(Counter(c)) #additional space required!


    3)]
    print(len(codons))
    print(trimmed_sequence)
    print(codons)

    # Take all codons until first stop codon
    coding_sequence  =  takewhile(lambda x: x not in stop_codons and len(x) == 3 , codons)


    return "{0}_".format(protein_sequence)
```

I first cd to desktop in terminal (Mac) then I run 
python the name of the code.py or python -t the name of the code

both situation I get error for example

**File "translate_dna2.py", line 34
    start = sequence.find('ATG')
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent**

the same for stop_codones etc

Comment: I rolled back your recent edits.  Please post a new question with a suitable title and a proper problem description if you have additional issues you need help with. (Upvoting the answer which helped you is optional, but would seem like a nice gesture.)

Comment: Could you check your last edit. Large amounts of the code seem to be missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On line with 'codontable' (line 6) you have a missing space. Should be:

```
def (...) :
----codontable
```

The proper indent for Python is one tabulation = 4 spaces. Also here:

```
----pat = re.compile(r"(TAA|TGA|TAG|ATG)")
----c = re.findall(pat,sequence)
----print(Counter(c))
```

Every dash means one space.

Comment: do you mean, I should remove the empty lines between the methods ?

Comment: No, empty lines are fine. I mean that every block needs to have four lines of indent with respect to header. I will update my post.

Comment: can you please update your post or modify the code, so that I will understand where the problem is !

Comment: I do have four space for ----codontable , and others

Comment: then update the code you posted so that others can see your changes and come up with another answer. in the code I see here, you don't

Comment: when I run the code, I get no output like this agr-wrk-stud22:Desktop Nemo$ python translate_dna2.py
agr-wrk-stud22:Desktop Nemo$

Comment: The error message clearly indicates an IndentationError, so this is almost certainly the right answer, even if finding the correct offending line is imprecise (especially if your posted code differs from the actual code you are having trouble with).

Comment: you get no output, or it doesn't compile? that's a difference

Comment: it does compile and no error was shown but the code does not provide any output

Comment: okay, then the problem you posed has been solved. please ask a separate question if you have different issues

Comment: @Michał Szydłowski I ask a separate question

Comment: great. the reason it's better this way, is that it avoids prolonged discussions in comments, and avoids confusion for other viewers as to what problem is being discussed

Comment: If you are still having trouble understanding indentation in Python, try https://python4kids.wordpress.com/getting-started/

Answer (score 0):

One of Python's main strengths is the availability of a huge number of high quality libraries for just about anything.  A good package for bioinformatics is [Biopython](http://biopython.org/wiki/Main_Page).  You have a FASTA record.  Save it to a file called "seq.fa", then do the following (after installing Biopython ofc):

```python
import Bio.SeqIO

with open("seq.fa") as f:
    record = Bio.SeqIO.parse(f, "fasta").next()
prot_seq = record.seq.translate()
print prot_seq.tostring()
```

Comment: Thanks @simleo but I am more thinking to do it without using any available packages so that I am more flexible in modifying/changing it